# Why doesn't Thread.Sleep register in Stopwatch?

Tags: .net, f#, sleep, stopwatch

I have the following program:

```
open System.Diagnostics
open System.Threading

[<EntryPoint>]
let main _ =
    let timer = Stopwatch ()
    printfn "begin"
    timer.Start ()
    Thread.Sleep 5000
    timer.Stop ()
    printfn "end"
    printfn "%i ms" timer.Elapsed.Milliseconds
    0
```

I was expecting it to print an elapsed time of 5000 ms or a bit more. It does pause for about 5 seconds between printing "begin" and "end". But it only prints "3 ms" or thereabouts. Why doesn't `Stopwatch` count the sleep time?

Comment: I believe it is because your timer is running on the same thread. So when your thread sleeps the timer stops?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Selthien, but it turns out to be a silly mistake, as noted in the answer. So silly in fact that I'll delete this question after a little while.

Comment: No, please don't delete the question @CarbonFlambe. It's silly, yes, but also very common: many people make the same mistake for the same reason you did - because the property names are not very intuitive. If you leave the question be, it will help somebody else in the future.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because the Elapsed property returns a TimeSpan, and the Milliseconds property of that TimeSpan is pretty small. If you use the ElapsedMilliseconds property, you should see a good value.

[Edit] You can also use timer.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds, (which is a float, not an int).

Comment: Yep, `Elapsed` returns only one component. It's 5 seconds plus 3 milliseconds.